# What can I use Lazarus for?

Tags: compiler-construction, lazarus

I was browsing the Ubuntu software center for compilers and came across Lazarus. It claims to be a cross-platform compiler that will let me develop for windows, OSX, and Linux. I did a little research but I only found information on how the compiler works, not specifically how I can use it. So I have a few questions.

What languages does it support?
Can I code in one language and not have to port it to another to use it for another?

Basically I'm wondering if this compiler is as awesome as it describes itself, because being able to use one compiler for everything, though it's lazy of me, is extremely efficient.

Thanks any help is appreciated!

Comment: Free Pascal. https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/lazarus-ide-0.9.30.2/

Comment: Here you will surely find your answer http://lazarus.freepascal.org/.

Comment: Thanks for all the help! I notice my question was put "on hold" due to being "opinion-based". I'd like to appeal this if possible just in case it could help someone else in the future, because what I asked was what languages does it support, and that would be an answer requiring a fact, I didn't ask for anyone's opinion on the program. Thanks again!

Comment: Only the Free Pascal compiler, but that compiler supports multiple Pascal dialects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lazarus is an opensource IDE for FreePascal compiler and replacement of Delphi and it uses FreePascal compiler and FreeComponents Library as its back end.

It is useful for development of portable applications in Object Pascal language.

Comment: (actually, the Delphi VCL is roughly split into the FPC FCL (non visual components) and Lazarus LCL (visual components, forms unit and above))

Comment: LCL is based on FCL, right?

Comment: While the LCL uses some FCL units (mostly in fcl-base), but it is not really a direct relation.  Most of the FCL isn't very coherent atm anyway. It is just a lot of leftover stuff.